# XPages - return shortName of user who is logged in

Tags: xpages

I was looking for a method getShortName() or attribute of UserName that would return the shortName/UserID of someone who has authenticated with the Domino server. Did a search on the forums, StackOverflow and was unable to find any such method except in the Registration Class.

I'll post my alternative solution below, but if anyone has a better solution I would love to hear it.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the formula command @NameLookup() to return items from a person document. Together with session.evaluate() you should be able to use it in XPages.

Try this:

```
session.evaluate('@NameLookup([EXHAUSTIVE];' + userName + ';"ShortName")');
```

Disclaimer: not tested at all.

Comment: Thanks Per. I modified my solution to: 

    var shortName = session.evaluate("@NameLookup([Exhaustive];\"" + @UserName() + "\";\"ShortName\")");
    shortName;

Comment: Frantisek, thankfully our shortname/userid field only has one entry per person.

Answer (score 0):

My solution follows:

```
var userName = @Name("[ABBREVIATE]" ,@UserName());
var shortName = @DbLookup([@DbName()[0],'names.nsf'],'($VIMPeople)',userName,"ShortName");
return shortName;
```

Comment: Use @NameLookup as suggested by Per. Will search in any directory configured

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of the NAB has the hidden view called ($NamesFieldLookup), but if I recall it will include the CN=Bugs Bunny/OU=ACME/O=COM in the first sorted column.  This would allow you to skip the first step of your code.  Other than that not aware of a provided method to get the short name.